# Conditional MOVE data from one sheet to another in google spreasheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I got the code online and added in the if statement myself and it did not work.
What i would like to achieve:

1. One column to indicate 'ok' . If 'ok' is present, that row of data will be moved to the other spreadsheet.

```js
    function moveData(){
      var app = SpreadsheetApp;
      var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var originalSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 4");
      var copySheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("RECORDS");
      var lc = originalSheet.getLastColumn();
      var lr = originalSheet.getLastRow();
      var originalData = originalSheet.getDataRange().getValues();

      for (var i=originalData.length-1; i>=1 ; --i){
        var crange = originalSheet.getRange(i, 37).getValue();
        if ( crange == 'ok' ){
          copySheet.getRange(copySheet.getLastRow()+1, 1, 1, 
          originalData[i].length).setValues([ originalData[i] ]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What's not working? Look for errors in View > Execution transcript. Minimize the number of variables (you're not using `lr` or `lc` at all) to cut down on API calls as well.

Comment: Have you check if you were  able to get the value of the column that indicate 'ok' string?